# nodejs decoded string from buffer returns multi line string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, buffer

I have a buffer which I want to decode so that I can treat it as an object.

I have the below setup

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var req = http.request(reqOptions, function(res) {
    ...
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var textChunk = decoder.write(chunk);
        console.log(textChunk);
    });
});
```

`textChunk returns` - note how this is on multiple lines.

```
{"aaa":true,"bbb":true, "cc
c":true, "ddd":true, "eee":true, "f
ff":true, "ggg":true}
```

so when I try and convert it to an object

```
JSON.parse(textChunk)
```

I get `Unexpected end of input`

How can I return my string as one line so that I can then treat it as an object.

```
{"aaa":true,"bbb":true, "ccc":true, "ddd":true, "eee":true, "fff":true, "ggg":true}
```

Comment: @ShanShan has a good answer. Why is textChunk on multiple lines to begin with? Are you storing it in Firebase with EOL characters?

Comment: Classic case of RTFM, it's on multiple lines because it's multiple `console.log()`...

Comment: @ShanShan my question was whether the displaying of the chunks on multiple lines was intentional as a representation of the original data stored in the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a string variable to concatenate all the chunks in, and then use your decoder at the end. Something like this:

```
var text = '';

res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    text += chunk;
});

res.on('end', function() {
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');
    var result = decoder.write(text);
    // Do something with the result
});
```

Comment: Good job on spotting that `console.log()` writes the arguments you pass in **and** a new line at the end of it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Isn't there a question of what's in the buffer to start with i.e. are there three chunks passed in resulting in a need to concatenate them?

Comment: The concatenation is necessary, although it somewhat depends on how the underlying stream exposes the data. Since the `res` stream in this case surfaces the data in multiple chunks, they need to be concatenated together to get the original string. But the chunking/concatenation doesn't introduce new lines. Those come from calling `console.log()` each time.

Comment: thanks, I tried something similar but didn't have the decode in on 'close'.  For the record as you suggested when I tried close I got nothing when I tried end this returned what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try request.js

`npm install request -g --save`

And pipe the result instead, MUCH simpler trust me

The whole http.request / response lines would be replaced by

`res.pipe(url)` with the result being a nice object returned to parse or consume by a service, factory, or service